# error in Grails validation while using "size"

Tags: grails

in my user domain i added a constrain on the contactNumber field as below :

```
contactNumber(size:7..13,matches: '\\d')
```

and in the BootStrap i'm making a new user as below :

```
def user = new Users("user", "password","xyz","user@user.com","123456711").save(failOnError: true)
```

but when i'm trying to run my application i get this error although the length for the contatNumber is within the range (7..13) ! :

```
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.sherif.Users' on field 'contactNumber': rejected value [123456711]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because it doesn't match your regex. Should be:

```
contactNumber(size:7..13, matches: '\\d+')
```